# ASP.Net 3.5 WebForms app - problems with images & subfolders in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I recently moved my development to a Windows 7 machine, and am having all sorts of trouble getting basic things to work. I have a pretty run-of-the-mill Web Forms app that is in .Net 3.5. It is developed in VS 2008. Having moved it to my new dev machine, I can't get the site to serve up any images (that are in an images/ folder), or apply any styling (stylesheets in a stylesheets/ folder). Not to mention that all my jQuery stuff is broken, given that my .js scripts are in a scripts/ folder. Given my newness to Windows 7 and its new flavor of IIS, my guess is that there is something(s) basic I'm just missing. But after hours of flailing, it is time to ask the SO crowd for help.

For what it's worth, I did a quick experiment. I created a new web site, and on the default.aspx page, added an image. Turns out that when I browse to that page, I see my text, but no image. Makes me wonder if IIS 7.5's security has been ratcheted down tons more than before.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it was an IIS installation thing - found the answer here:  http://gurustop.net/blog/2009/10/12/funny-problem-windows-7-iis-7-5-images-css-not-showing/